# Finding the value of $n$ in this question?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Find the value of n for which the quadratic equation 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x+k-1)(x+k) =10n
$$
has solutions $α$ and $α+1$ for some $α$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

If you expand the sum appearing in the lhs, you have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x+k-1)(x+k) =\frac{n}{3} \left(n^2+3 n x+3 x^2-1\right)$$ whish is quadratic equation for which you have conditions to be fulfilled.

I am sure that you can take from here.0

**Added later to this answer**

If you expand the term in the summation, you have $$(x+k-1)(x+k) =x^2-x+2 k x-k+k^2$$ Then $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x+k-1)(x+k) =\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2-\sum_{k=1}^{n}x+(2x-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$$ that is to say $$S=nx^2-nx+(2x-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$$ but (Faulhaber's formulas) $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)$$ and  $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1)$$ and then the result.

Comment: Develop and you will need the sum of $k$'s and the sum of $k^2$'s for $k$ from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Look at my profile. I shall complete my answer for a complete clarification.